# Custom UITableViewCell layout changes on click (iOS7 only)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

In order to get my app in line with guidelines for iOS8, I've implemented auto layout in my custom table view cell. On iOS8 this looks fine - the cells are laid out as I'd like at all screen sizes. On iOS7 however, the text boxes start out with only one line of text each, with the remaining text cut off (with an ellipsis). When touching the button however (on touch down), the cell's layout changes and it looks more like it does on iOS8. I can't seem to find what is being called here, and there aren't any constraint errors/warnings coming up in the console. Any idea how I might debug something like this, or is this a known bug in iOS8 so far?

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed too when using self-sizing cells made in a storyboard. I was able to get it to work correctly by calling layoutIfNeeded in the cell's didMoveToSuperview method,

```
-(void)didMoveToSuperview { 
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
}
```